# Transpose google spread sheet row values to column in different sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a  google spreadsheet that has Sheet1 (tab 1) column values I want to be row value in a column in sheet (tab 2)

So I wrote formula `={'Sheet1'!A2:A35}` and it does give me column values from sheet value but the outputs to multiple row (vertically)

is it possible that the row values of column A in sheet 1 to become column values of a single row in sheet 2.

the reason why I want is because in sheet 2 they act has Header to columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
=TRANSPOSE({SHEET1!A2:A35})
```

Did the job what I was after.

Answer (score 1):

You actually include the answer in your own title. Use this:

`=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A2:A35)`

Comment: yes, bad habit got me away form googling, but quickly got what I was looking for and I answered my question.